# Appending a class based on scroll depth relative to another element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to append a class based on scroll depth, however I'm getting a `"getBoundingClientRect is not a function"` in console and see no effect.

See here:
https://www.regatta.pl/short-femme-highton-seal-grey/?overflow

JS used:

```js
var  leftSection = document.getElementsByClassName('js-detail-product'),
     leftSectionTop = leftSection.getBoundingClientRect().top,
     rightSection = document.getElementsByClassName('js-product-info-main'),
     rightSectionHeight = rightSection.getBoundingClientRect().height;

if(leftSectionTop <= rightSectionHeight) {
      rightSection.className = ('active');
} else if(leftSectionTop >= rightSectionHeight) {
      rightSection.className =  ('inactive');
}
```

Comment: Double check leftSection is really an element  or its undefined for it's not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    //insert all your code here
  });
```

Comment: It's worked! But overall it is not working as intended, any ideas?

Comment: @WojciechŚwięch, it is hard to solve the issue without a demo code. Could you create one?

Comment: Can you refer to https://www.regatta.pl/short-femme-highton-seal-grey/?overflow?

Comment: @WojciechŚwięch, do you want to hide the `js-product-info-main` block?

Comment: The js-product-info-main (right section) is by default on a fixed position. When user scrolls to js-detail-product (left section), then I want to append a class to it for a relative position.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array.

Try this:

```js
leftSection = document.getElementsByClassName('js-detail-product')[0],
leftSectionTop = leftSection.getBoundingClientRect().top,

rightSection = document.getElementsByClassName('js-product-info-main')[0],
rightSectionHeight = rightSection.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Or may be for more safety:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    allLeftSections = document.getElementsByClassName('js-detail-product');
    if(allLeftSections.length > 0) {
        leftSection = allLeftSections[0],
        leftSectionTop = leftSection.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    }

    allRightSection = document.getElementsByClassName('js-product-info-main');
    if(allRightSection.length > 0) {
        rightSection = allRightSection[0],
        rightSectionHeight = rightSection.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    }
});
```